# How to Return last and next 25th of month

Tags: sql-server, date

I need to return both the last instance of the 25th of the month before today and next instance of the 25th after today in SQL Server 2014.

I don't have code ready for this as I'm not SQL proficient

As an example

- if Today is 28th June, I need to return 25th June and 25th July
- If Today is 15th June, I need to return 25th May and 25th June

There wont be a case where this is requested on the 25th of each month, so no validation required there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea using `DATEFROMPARTS` (assumes you're using 2012+, but with 2008 having 4 weeks of support left, a "*safe*" assumption no?):

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(V.Today),MONTH(V.Today),25),
       DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(V.Today),MONTH(V.Today),25))
FROM (VALUES(DATEADD(DAY, -25,GETDATE()))) V(Today);
```

For today, that returns `2019-05-25` and `2019-06-25` and returns the correct values for your example: I.e.:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(V.Today),MONTH(V.Today),25),
       DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(V.Today),MONTH(V.Today),25))
FROM (VALUES(DATEADD(DAY, -25,'20190628'))) V(Today);
```

Comment: Yes, 2014, should have specified